# Трудности в чтении регистров с помощью I2C

Tags: c, stm32, электроника

Надо получать значения угловой скорости с гироскопа [модуля Амперки](http://amperka.ru/product/troyka-imu-10-dof). Но даже при обычном обращении к регистру идентификатора возвращаются какие то кривые значения, не соответствующие реальности. Уже сутки потратил и не добился даже этого не говоря о скоростях) Использую библиотеку HAL.
Вот как обращаюсь:

```
void Accel_Ini(void)
{
        uint16_t ctrl = 0x0000;
        HAL_Delay(500);
        if(Accel_ReadID()!=0x68) while(1);
        AccInit(ctrl);
}

uint8_t Accel_ReadID(void)
{
uint8_t ctrl = 0x00;
        ctrl = Accel_IO_Read(0x68,0x0F);
        return ctrl;
}

uint8_t Accel_IO_Read(uint16_t DeviceAddr, uint8_t RegisterAddr)
{
        return I2Cx_ReadData(DeviceAddr, RegisterAddr);
}

static uint8_t I2Cx_ReadData(uint16_t Addr, uint8_t Reg)
{

        HAL_StatusTypeDef status = HAL_OK;

        uint8_t value = 0;

        status = HAL_I2C_Mem_Read(&hi2c1, Addr, Reg, I2C_MEMADD_SIZE_8BIT, &value, 1, 0x10000);

        if(status != HAL_OK)
                    while(1);

        return value;

}
```

Скажите, если не сложно, что я делаю не так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А вы его откалибровали перед использованием?

Comment: @0andriy какой смысл калибровать если я даже значения прочитать не могу?)

Comment: Вы определитесь *"значения, не соответствующие реальности"* или  *"значения прочитать не могу"*. Первое — калибровка. Второе — доступ.

Comment: @0andriy Допустим, если я обращаюсь по адресу где содержится информация о идентификаторе устройства, я получаю совсем не те значения